# Craft CMS Integration with Node

Tags: plugin-elementapi, craft-features

## Question 1

I have a Node/Express application where the users are registered and are using some kind of service. I want to have a list of the registered users and their info inside Craft CMS admin panel.  Node/Express may use MongoDB or MySQL. This kind of hybrid to work, I assume that Node/Express and Craft CMS should be using the same MySQL database? Is this possible at all to integrate them?

## Question 2

Can you generally review what the architecture of the application would be in the scenario below?
Lets say we want a web application where the users are registering, uploading their pictures in members area, writing some logs about themselves, but on the other hand, inside the members area they are able to see content from Craft CMS.  Lets say frontend is done via REACT, and the frontend team just sends us request calls and we should just answer. What technology would you use and how to accomplish this? Must it be done in php?